# How to check when text entered by way of VBA input box exists in range of cells form hidden sheet.

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working Excel sheet that when opened the user is asked to enter a product type. This is done by VBA code InputBox and places the input in cell A6 of the active sheet. I have a hidden sheet that lists all the possible types in cells A2:A160. I would like to have a way to check that what the user entered is valid and if not to try again.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will search the hidden worksheet(Change Sheet2 to the hidden worksheet name). and a `MsgBox`. You should change `ActiveSheet` to the actual worksheet.

```
Sub FindInHiddenSht()

    Dim findVal As Variant

    With Sheet2 'Your hidden worksheet
        Set findVal = .Cells.Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Range("A6").Value, After:=.Cells(1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
    End With

        If findVal Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not Found"

        Else
            MsgBox "Found at " & findVal.Address
        End If

End Sub
```